# How to rewrite the sql script where in join case statement is used

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql code:

```
select t1.*
from t1
join t3 on t3.id = t1.id
join t2 on case when t1.date is null then t2.date = t3.date else t1.date = t2.date
```

but it is not optimal to use case statement in joins
Is there a way to rewrite this, nothing comes to my mind

Comment: Write two queries and `UNION` them. Since you use `INNER JOINS` these are basically different filters on `t1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first swap `t2.date` so that it always occurs at the left hand side of the comparison operation:

```
case when t1.date is null then t2.date = t3.date else t1.date = t2.date
```

Becomes:

```
case when t1.date is null then t2.date = t3.date else t2.date = t1.date
```

Then we observe that `t2.date` always compared in both cases of the case statement, i.e. it is non-null. We can express the case-statement in the following coalesce statement:

```
t2.date = coalesce(t1.date, t3date)
```

Which looks a lot cleaner, but is still functionally the same as the case statement.

Mind that if you're not projecting any values from `t2` and `t3`, it will be faster to do a `where date in (select date from t2) or date in (select date from t3)`.

Comment: I like your `COALESCE` solution better, and I don't think it will perform worse in PostgreSQL.